# Amplitude response of Lynn's low pass filter at the 3dB cutoff frequency

Tags: lowpass-filter

I am referring to the calculations in https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse474/18wi/labs/l8/QRSdetection.pdf for the second order Lynn's low pass filter.

On the third page, the author mentions the transfer function used as:

$$
H(z)=\frac{(1−z^{-6})^2}{ (1−z^{-1})^2 }
$$

The amplitude frequency response for this is given as:
$$
|H(e^{j\omega T})|=\frac{\sin^2(3\omega T)}{\sin^2(\omega T/2)}
$$
Now, he has calculated the 3dB cutoff frequency to be around 11 Hz for the sampling frequency of 200 Hz (i.e. sampling time = 0.005 seconds). Substituting these values in the above equation for amplitude response, I get:
$$
|H(e^{j\omega_c T})|=\frac{\sin^2(3 \cdot 11 \cdot 0.005)}{\sin^2(11 \cdot 0.005/2)} = \frac{0.026979}{0.000756} = 35.69
$$
At the 3dB cutoff frequency indicated, shouldn't the amplitude response work out to around 0.707 and not 35.69? Where is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: Did you forget that $\omega = 2\pi f$ ?

Comment: @Ben , yes that was it! Now |H(ωcT)| works out to 25 which is ~ 0.7 of the peak amplitude (gain) of 36. Hope this understanding is correct

Comment: That's one weird filter with pole cancellation. You can just do an FIR with b = [1 2 3 4 5 6 5 4 3 2 1] and get the same result.

Comment: @Hilmar yes that is possible, but it is expressed in a recursive form here so that it has a low computational cost. For details, you can have a look at section 7.1.4 of https://fdocuments.in/document/biomedical-digital-signal-processing-tompkins.html

Comment: I see the intent but I don't think it's a correct assumption, at least not these days. You can break this down into a simple FIR filter with b = [1 0 2 0 3 0 2 0 1] followed by two first order integrators. This will on most platforms be significantly faster than a recursive implementation. It's about the same number of arithmetic operations but much easier to pipeline efficiently and it can be made parallel and make use of SIMD instructions.

Comment: @Ben you should add as an answer (even though so simple it will close this out as an otherwise unanswered question, and something others may run into)

Comment: @Hilmar This is meant for use cases like for gathering signals on wearables with small microprocessors. With higher sampling frequencies, and lower cutoff frequency requirements, the number of zeros to be placed increases as per this filter design recommendations. More zeros are required to have a sharper slope at the cutoff frequency To still keep it computationally efficient, the recursive form is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your mistake, you forgot that $ \omega = 2\pi f$